# List places Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

List all the rooms defined in the tenant.
Does this API supports pagination? I am getting 100 results at a time but there is no nextLink info in the response. How can I get list of all rooms.

Comment: Try to add `$top={totalCount}` to your api.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members.Thank you.

Comment: Question to OP: do you know hoe to add places into a tenant?

Answer (score 0):

The default page size is 100, you can use `$top` to customize the page size.

Please see: [OData query parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/place-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters).